# Best way to say Thanks to all the helpful people here?

Tags: discussion

if not just to say Thanks here for making this a great electronics year for me!  I've learned so much here and appreciate greatly all the time and obvious care people have put into the answers to my question.  Even when the answer was "why are you such a dummy," expressed with various levels of directness.

You all know who you are... I just hope you're reading meta!

Comment: Well, I'd say that one great (indirect) way would be to contribute back to the community by answering questions!

Answer (score 1):

Some members, though definitely not most, frequent the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) area, where you can ping them directly by @reemrevnivek (or @whatever). If their name doesn't "pop up" when partially typed, then the ping probably won't work unless you point to their chat history. One way to do that is to go to the 'info' page for the chat room and click '[Frequently In Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15/electrical-engineering?id=15&tab=general&users=frequent)', click one, click the '[recent](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1764/w5vo?tab=recent)' tab, then click the permalink symbol on the left-hand-side of one of the chat bubbles (it'll pop into view upon mouseover). The address will be something like:
`http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15?m=2889163#2889163`
Copy the number on the end, `2889163`, then head to the chat room. Type `:2889163` and that user will be pinged (and it'll look like you're replying to the referred chat bubble, but oh well).

That was complicated. A better option is to spread general cheer with [ebeers](http://ebeer.org/).

I often thank users for thoughtful answers in comments directly on their answer.

Comment: reemrevnivek changed his name to his actual name as kevin vermeer, not to say you are out of date with chatting or anything.